# LightSwitch Database connection Lost When the application is in idle

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

i am using sql server database to the lightswitch application. Everything in the application works fine while it is in use. when sitting idle for period of time the database connection lost i need to close and open the application again to get the database connection. how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your question as been answered in the LightSwitch forum post where you asked the same question.

[LightSwitch Database connection Lost When the application is in idle](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/lightswitch/thread/177427d6-9470-429f-8f04-9589a74f6e3a/#8ced3bdd-4c85-46a0-b97b-a9ee5d900d97)

```
Public Class Application

    Private Sub Application_Initialize()
        Me.Details.ClientTimeout = 1000
    End Sub
End Class
```